# SQL Server split by comma

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a question about splitting column values in T-SQL.
I have

```
Address_col

Nevada,USA
Tokyo,Japan
Hanoi,Vietnam
```

I want to split the values by comma to

```
Address_col     Country

Navada          USA
Tokyo           Japan
Hanoi           Vietnam
```

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @T table (Address_col varchar(20))

insert into @T values
('Nevada,USA'),
('Tokyo,Japan'),
('Hanoi,Vietnam')

select left(Address_col, charindex(',', Address_col)-1) as Address_col,
       stuff(Address_col, 1, charindex(',', Address_col), '') as Country
from @T
```

**Update:**
Split a string with three parts can look like this:
declare @T table (Address_col varchar(20))

```
insert into @T values
('Nevada,USA,World'),
('Tokyo,Japan,World'),
('Hanoi,Vietnam,World')

select parsename(C, 3),
       parsename(C, 2),
       parsename(C, 1) 
from @T
  cross apply (select replace(Address_col, ',', '.')) as T(C)
```

Comment: if I have NEVADA,USA,WORLD I wanna split to 3 columns How can I do?

Comment: @aliasosx - Updated answer with a way to split string with three values. Note, there can not be any `,` or `.` in the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two parts then this is the simplest I can think of.

select  SUBSTRING(Address_col,1,CHARINDEX(',',Address_col)-1) as Address_col,
        SUBSTRING(Address_col,CHARINDEX(',',Address_col)+1,LEN(Address_col)) as Country