# How do I split one string value separated by semicolon and insert it into 3 separate columns using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-insert

I want to take a string like this 7;132030;00102 from column misc2  in table data_import and insert 7 into column Department and insert 132030  into column job and 00102 in column CostCode in table  Data_Timecards.

Table Data_Import

[image]

What Table Data_Timecards should look like after insert

[image]

Comment: Sorry, there is no function like split() in mssql. You need to do this with the transact-sql string manipulation functions available. Maybe somebody will give you an example code here.

Comment: This is probably the closest to what the OP is asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044011/sql-server-split-by-comma essentially by using a combination of `substring` & `charindex` you can split `misc2` string which is delimited by comma and split it into three columns. Regarding how to insert it into another table (assuming you have a common column between the 2 tables) you could use `update` with an `inner/left join` to acheive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty ugly looking solution but will do the job

**Query**

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(100) = '7;132030;001202'

SELECT  LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var) - 1)     AS [Department]
        ,SUBSTRING(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var) + 1, 
         LEN(@Var)- LEN(LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var)))- 
         LEN(RIGHT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@Var))))) AS [Job]
       , RIGHT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@Var))-1) AS [CostCode]
```

**Result Set**

```
Department  Job     CostCode
    7       132030  001202
```

**Data Into Destination Table**

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table_Name (Department, Job, CostCode)

SELECT  LEFT(misc2, CHARINDEX(';', misc2) - 1)   
        ,SUBSTRING(misc2, CHARINDEX(';', misc2) + 1, 
         LEN(misc2)- LEN(LEFT(misc2, CHARINDEX(';', misc2)))- 
         LEN(RIGHT(misc2, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(misc2))))) 
       , RIGHT(misc2, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(misc2))-1) 
 FROM Source_Table
```